# Generating a set of random numbers that form sum under two combinations

Tags: python, matlab, heuristics

I want to generate 16 random non-negative integers, say a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p.

```
a+b+c+d = a particular sum
e+f+g+h = another sum
i+j+k+l = another sum
m+n+o+p = another sum
```

This much is pretty easy. But, the trouble is,

```
a+e+i+m = another sum
b+f+j+n = another sum
c+g+k+o = another sum
d+h+l+p = another sum
```

I have written a very elaborate code in Matlab that generates numbers which satisfy the conditions. The code takes around 0.5 seconds and generates around 920 such arrays after running for 1000 iterations. The number 16 is a prototype. The actual number is 1794. So, obviously what I have written isn't gonna be very helpful. Any help would be great!

Thanks.

Comment: What does "random" mean to you here?

Comment: I don't think the distribution of the numbers means much to me, if that is what you are getting at. Please clarify, if that is not what you meant. Thank you!

Comment: What is the domain of your inputs for a..p ? 1 to 100? negatives? floating point values or integers? Are you trying to find all possible arrays for a limited domain? or just generate M arrays of length N with no domain restriction as fast as possible? (that satisfy those summation requirements, of course)

Comment: Apologies for not mentioning those details. I will edit the question.

Comment: And, M arrays of length N, where N is 16 in the illustration. And, M could be a sufficiently large number, like 1000.

Comment: but you want one solution or all possible solutions? why do you say random?

Comment: I want to generate a large set of integers that fit these conditions. Neither one, nor all possible solutions. If not random, then how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be solved as integer program with random weighting cost function, then everytime you run this code, you get a different solution.

```
A = [A1; -A1; -eye(N)]
b = [sum1; sum2; ...; sumM ; -sum1; -sum2; ... ; -sumM; zeros(N,1)];
intcon = N;
f = randn(N,1);  %random cost function, will generate different solution everytime
solution = intlinprog(f,intcon,A,b);
```

where `A1` is a matrix that represent your sums, in your example it will be

```
A1 = [1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0;
0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0;
0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0;
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1];
```

In few words, you transform your constraints to `Ax <= b`.

Improved representation:

```
Aeq = A1
beq = [sum1; sum2; ...; sumM];
ub = inf*ones(N,1);
lb = zeros(N,1);
intcon = N;
f = randn(N,1);  %random cost function, will generate different solution everytime
solution = intlinprog(f,intcon,[],[], Aeq, beq, lb, ub);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This will help me. But, I have a doubt. In the A and b matrices, A=[A1] and b=[sum1; sum2;..;sumM;] wouldn't be enough? I don't understand why you added the rest. Could you please explain that? Thank you.

Comment: this program takes around 0.02 sec to find a solution with 16 variables.

Comment: the f is the cost function, so you search for a solution that minimises f'*x, if you set f = rand then you have a random cost function every time.  The -eye(N) and zeros in b are used to constraint the solution to be non-negative. Actually there is a more elegant way I am going to add now.

Comment: Thank you! This way is much clearer for me. Unfortunately, I don't have the optimization tool box right now. So, I need to ask one more question. I hope you don't mind answering. The examples at Matlab website generate non-integer solutions. But, I need integers. Any thoughts on how I should go about this?

Comment: the intcon tells the program how many integer variables you have, since we set intcon to N, it generates only integers.